# Can we implement Role and Membership in MVC4 using oracle database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g

I have implemented roles and membership in mvc4 using SQL database. I want to do same using oracle database. I found many articles on Google but not giving exact solution. Can any one help me. Any link will also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to implement your own provider, but there should be no reason why this can't be easily achieved.

It's likely the existing Sql Provider uses SqlServer specific features (but you won't know till you try it).

If it does, then write your own provider, using the many examples available through Google, but use queries written against Oracle. You'll then be able to use Oracle specific features. You'll probably need to create the DB schema yourself in Oracle.

Comment: Sir i am new to MVC. I achieved this using Google help. I don't know which provider i need to create. Just give me some hint i will do rest. I created same schema in Oracle. But didn't worked.

Comment: Thanks all. I implemented one oracle provider for oracle role membership. It's difficult but now working as per my requirement.